# What is the proper way to determine if any duplicate elements are present between multiple arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am having an issue trying to determine if my arrays contain any duplicate integers. For my Lo Shu Magic Square project, we are to create three different 1-dimensional arrays along with different functions to determine if the input is magic square numbers. I was able to make all other functions work but I cant seem to figure out how to check if the combined array inputs are all unique. Can anyone help? Here is my source code for bool checkUnique.

```
bool checkUnique(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int TOTAL_NUM)
{
    int combinedArray[] = { arrayRow1[0], arrayRow1[1], arrayRow1[2],
                            arrayRow2[0], arrayRow2[1], arrayRow3[2],
                            arrayRow3[0], arrayRow3[1], arrayRow3[2] };
    for (int counter = 0; counter < TOTAL_NUM; counter++)
    {
        for (int j = counter; j < TOTAL_NUM; j++)
        {
            if (j != counter) {

                if (combinedArray[counter] == combinedArray[j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I added all elements(TOTAL_NUM = 9) from three different arrays into a new array called combinedArray. When I ran my code and entered 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, result is still showing that there are duplicates. I tried different methods I found online but still cant get this function to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: FYI -- `return std::set<int>(combinedArray, combinedArray + TOTAL_NUM).size() == 9);`  That replaces your entire set of `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite close to a correct solution, which might look like this:

```
bool checkUnique(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int TOTAL_NUM)
{
    int combinedArray[] = { arrayRow1[0], arrayRow1[1], arrayRow1[2],
                            arrayRow2[0], arrayRow2[1], arrayRow3[2],
                            arrayRow3[0], arrayRow3[1], arrayRow3[2] };
    for (int counter = 0; counter < TOTAL_NUM; counter++)
    {
        for (int j = counter; j < TOTAL_NUM; j++)
        {
            if (j != counter) {

                if (combinedArray[counter] == combinedArray[j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    return false;   
}
```

The only change relative to your code is that I moved `return false;` behind the loops. Why? Because you need to check *all* pairs before you can assert that there are no duplicates.

This solution might be further improved by changing the starting index of the inner loop:

```
bool checkUnique(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int TOTAL_NUM)
{
    int combinedArray[] = { arrayRow1[0], arrayRow1[1], arrayRow1[2],
                            arrayRow2[0], arrayRow2[1], arrayRow3[2],
                            arrayRow3[0], arrayRow3[1], arrayRow3[2] };
    for (int counter = 0; counter < TOTAL_NUM; counter++)
    {
        for (int j = counter + 1; j < TOTAL_NUM; j++)
        {
            if (combinedArray[counter] == combinedArray[j]) 
                 return true;
        }        
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Here I changed the initializer of the inner loop into `int j = counter + 1` so that I'm sure that `j` will never be equal to `counter`.

In this solution you need to make up to 36 comparisons. Alternative approaches:

- sort `combinedArray` and check via `std::unique` whether it contains duplicates.
- insert the elements into `std::set` and check if its size is 9

Since your array is small, these more universal solutions may be not optimal, you'd need to make tests.

Finally a side remark:  try to use consistent names to your variables.  `counter` looks very different from `j`, which suggests that there's a fundamental difference between the two loop control variables. But there's none: they're very similar to each other. So give them similar names. In the same spirit, please use more useful function names. For example, I'd prefer `allUnique` that would return `true` if and only if all input umbers are unique.    Compare `if (checkUnique(a, b, c, 9))` with `if (allUnique(a, b, c, 9))`. Of course this, in fact, should be called  `if allUnique(a, b, c, 3)`, because the information about array lengths is more fundamental than about the effective buffer length.

### EDIT

Actually, you have not defined precisely what the expected output of your function is. If you assume that `checkUnique` should return `true` if all numbers are different, then rename it to something more significant and swap all `true` and `false`:

```
bool allUnique(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int TOTAL_NUM)
{
    int combinedArray[] = { arrayRow1[0], arrayRow1[1], arrayRow1[2],
                            arrayRow2[0], arrayRow2[1], arrayRow3[2],
                            arrayRow3[0], arrayRow3[1], arrayRow3[2] };
    for (int counter = 0; counter < TOTAL_NUM; counter++)
    {
        for (int j = counter + 1; j < TOTAL_NUM; j++)
        {
            if (combinedArray[counter] == combinedArray[j]) 
                 return false;
        }        
    }
    return true;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your suggestions. I tried to locate the return value outside of the loop earlier and it did not work. I just copied your answer and ran the compiler but I am still getting wrong result. For example, I entered 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 and expected Not a magic square since there are duplicates, but its saying its Magic Square

Comment: ive added my main function and IsMagicSquare definition to see if you could look over to see if theres something wrong.

Comment: I don't see any `IsMagicSquare`

Comment: You need to check the sums in colums, rows and diagonals, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square
Generate these 8 sums and check that they have the same values. If it is a class assignment, don't bother to be "smart" and write "smart code". You can repeat lots of code and concentrate on it to run correctly.

Comment: Then decide what you want from Stack Overflow. Your question regards only uniqueness.

Comment: Im sorry if I caused any confusion. I wanted to see if someone could check my isUnique function code that I posted because I kept getting wrong outputs. With the modified code you provided, I ran the compiler (running through only the isUnique function), but I m getting outputs that were not expected still. For example, even when I input all 1s, I expected "not magic square," but instead, I received "It is Magic Square. " So I added my main function and the isMagic function (where I call the isUnique function) in the comments section to see if there is something else I'm missing.

Comment: Don't post code in comments: you can always edit your question, just as I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. My program is working now thanks to your help and pointers. Believe it or not, Ive been working on this project for two weeks, and was really ready to give up and just submit it. I even went to our class designated tutor but she could not help me too. So thank you!

Comment: There is  an up arrow or something similar  to upvote and/or accept the answer that has helped :-)